# How to transfer files via infrared on Linux?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, infrared, irda

I know this is a **way too old** technology but I've got some files inside a **very old cellphone** that I need to transfer to a **very old computer**.

So far my Infrared USB device works well, it's detected by the machine (`lsusb` output):

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0df7:0620 Mobile Action Technology, Inc. MA-620 Infrared Adapter
```

I've tried to send the file over `MMS` and even `email` (it lacks bluetooth, not to mention USB). But this cellphones's firmware doesn't let me attach the files. The file was originally transfered via IrDA, and it only has an internal memory (a whole 2 million bytes! whoa!).

I found a package called `irda-utils`, but it seems that there are only two executables: `irdaping` and `irdadump`. I think the dump utility might do the job (which as far as I can see it's kind of a version of `tcpdump` but for IrDA), but I don't even know how to process the received frames.

Could [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/160297/how-to-use-irda-adapter-as-serial-port) may be what I'm looking for?

**EDIT**

While reading through the [Linux Infrared HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Infrared-HOWTO/) I found about the [OpenObex](http://openobex.sourceforge.net/about.html) project, which may be what I'm looking for...

**UPDATE**

So far I've got the connection going, my cellphone is detected by `irdadump`:

```
00:19:43.951224 xid:cmd ffffffff < 5a2b330e S=6 s=* ALCATEL OT756 hint=b125 [ PnP Modem Fax Telephony IrCOMM IrOBEX ] (31) 
00:19:44.002219 snrm:cmd ca=fe pf=1 2980c3fd < 5a2b330e new-ca=66 
    LAP QoS: Baud Rate=115200bps Max Turn Time=500ms Data Size=2048B Window Size=1 Add BOFS=0 Min Turn Time=10000us Link Disc=40s (32) 
00:19:44.002658 ua:rsp ca=66 pf=1 2980c3fd > 5a2b330e 
    LAP QoS: Baud Rate=115200bps Max Turn Time=500ms Data Size=2048B Window Size=7 Add BOFS=0 Min Turn Time=5000us Link Disc=12s (31)
```

but `obex_tcp` seems to timeout the connection:

```
[root@**** *****]# obex_tcp 
Send and receive files over TCP OBEX
Waiting for files
Timeout waiting for connection
[root@**** *****]#
```

My cellphone returns a connection error. Is `obex` the correct software to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obex_tcp is the wrong tool (TCP is not related to IrDA).
You need either ircp (comes with openobex) or obexpushd (depends on openobex).

Comment: The problem is that obex_push (I think that's the name of the command on Fedora) looks for a bluetooth device and a bluetooth signal. I have a hope on ircp but I don't seem to find [a way to change the baud rate](http://superuser.com/questions/764744/how-to-change-irda-bitrate-on-linux) (my cellphone requires a lower speed to wok).

Comment: Don't assume that Fedora has the commands named any different. See e.g. http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/i386/o/openobex-apps-1.7.1-3.fc21.i686.html: /usr/bin/ircp. The other program (obexpushd) does not seem to be packaged for Fedora. You can find it at https://www.gitorious.org/obexpushd

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that binary, by the way, I think this problem is related to [this other question](http://superuser.com/questions/764744/how-to-change-irda-bitrate-on-linux).

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried Ircp Tray? It's a GUI application designed for that and uses the OBEX Push protocol.

https://launchpad.net/ircp-tray

Should be available in all Linux distributions.

Comment: I see that you're the mantainer, I'm on fedora and don't have my hardware with me currently, is launchpad the only channel for communication?

Comment: @arielnmz yes.

For general IrDa setup on Linux try translating these articoles: https://www.dnax.it/tag/irda