# How to change IrDA bitrate on Linux?

Tags: linux, infrared, irda

I've got this connection working between my linux machine via an IrDA dongle an this alcatel OT756.

So far the `irdadump` command tells me that my device is there:

```
04:10:12.238144 xid:cmd ffffffff < 87de81ea S=6 s=* ALCATEL OT756 hint=b125 [ PnP Modem Fax Telephony IrCOMM IrOBEX ] (31) 
04:10:12.288145 snrm:cmd ca=fe pf=1 1a10d99c < 87de81ea new-ca=42 
    LAP QoS: Baud Rate=115200bps Max Turn Time=500ms Data Size=2048B Window Size=1 Add BOFS=0 Min Turn Time=10000us Link Disc=40s (32) 
04:10:12.288638 ua:rsp ca=42 pf=1 1a10d99c > 87de81ea 
    LAP QoS: Baud Rate=115200bps Max Turn Time=500ms Data Size=2048B Window Size=7 Add BOFS=0 Min Turn Time=5000us Link Disc=12s (31)
```

As you can see, the **Baud Rate** is set to **115200 bps**, however, my phone only works at **[19200 bps](http://osdir.com/ml/linux.drivers.gammu/2004-02/msg00062.html)**. But I can't find how or where to change this setting. Not even the documentation nor the [IrDA HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Infrared-HOWTO/) tells how.

How can I change the **baud rate**?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but I expect one needs to make the device appear in `/dev/` as a serial port (e.g. `/dev/ttyS1`). Then `stty` (see `man 1 stty`). Not tested.

Comment: That makes sense, sadly I don't have my irda hardware around (it's been 6 years! haha) but will try as soon as I get my hands on it again